# Генерация кораблей на поле морского поля

Tags: delphi

У меня есть двумерный массив типа `Byte[,]`, содержащий состояние клетки:

```
type 
field = array[1..10,1..10] of Byte;
```

Клетка поля может иметь значения:

```
cc_none = 0; // Пусто 
cc_fill = 1; // Есть корабль
```

Мне нужно случайным образом сгенерировать корабли:

- 4 однопалубных;
- 3 двухпалубных;
- 2 трёхпалубных;
- 1 четырёхпалубный.

(желательно чтобы они могли быть не только прямыми, но и уголком или ещё как-нибудь).

Размещать нужно по правилам морского боя: рядом корабли находиться не могут, и по диагонали тоже.

Comment: А что вы сами пробовали? Какие сложности в случайной расстановке?

Comment: Сложность в том, чтобы корабли не стояли вместе и по диагонали!

Comment: Это несложно, надо просто начать. Дома лежит исходник

Comment: как вариант, если неохото писать логику генерации, можешь записать заранее шаблоны расстановки, например штук 10-15 и просто выбирать случайную из шаблонов )

Comment: а учитывая, что можно по часовой стрелке крутить и зеркально отображать (и это будут правильные расположения), то это сразу увеличивает кол-во вариантов в 8 раз.

Comment: о, идея небольшая пришла, выбирает случайную координату на поле, пытаемся поставить корабль, если не получается по правилам расстановки, перемещаемся на правую клетку, опять пытаемся, и т.д. доходим до конца, переходим на следующую строку 1го столбца, и т.д. С каждым новым кораблем рандомим стартовую ячейку.

Comment: Начинать расстановку нужно с большого корабля. Его ставим случайным образом (вначале генерируем направление, а потом выбираем из диапазона (1..10, 1..7) для вертикального и (1..7, 1..10) для горизонтального. Таким способом его всегда установим. Дальше в цикле пытаемся поставить два трехпалубных (1..10 и 1..8). Но проверку можно делать минимальную - что корабли не пересекаются. А потом, когда все расставлены, запускается процедура проверки корректности расстановки. Она понадобиться также, когда нужно будет проверить правильно ли пользователь все расставил. Если что-то не так,генерируем ещё раз

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего сделать матрицу "занятости" - то есть, после того, как поставили корабль, в отдельной матрице огораживаете вокруг него точки.

При установке нового корабля проверяете, чтоб сам корабль не попадал в эти поля. Если попадает, то поворачиваете. Если все-таки нет - ставите в другое место.

Точки выбирать можно просто рендомно (кораблей не так много относительно поля), только начинать нужно с самого длинного корабля.

Для начала лучше ставить прямы корабли, а потом модержнизировать для гнутых.

В принципе в инте можете поискать исходники, но так не будет никакого удовольствия. Пробуйте.

UPD-----------------

Более интересная задача, продумывать AI для играющего компьютера (если будете писать баталии комп-человек). Стрелять просто рендомно - не слишком интересно. Подглядывать - плохо (комп не должен учитывать при работе матрицу кораблей человека - только ту, которую он "прострелял").

Comment: Вот небольшое исследование оптимальных стратегий (читал в детстве): http://mathemlib.ru/books/item/f00/s00/z0000020/st005.shtml

Answer (score 0):

код конечно нужно оптимизировать, поля классов инкапсулировать, и т.д. но в конечном счете получиться должно что-то вроде этого...

p.s. оставил вам возможность прописать 4палубники, так будет проще понять принцип кода... и рандомно выбирать первую ячейку кораблей:) (уж на этом не хотелось останавливаться)

общий принцип довольно простой... выбранную ячейку проверяем (по ее типу)... свободна ли она, если свободна (к примеру ставим 2палубник), то смотрим все ячейки вокруг нее, если среди них так же есть "свободная", то меняем тип ячеек со "свободной"(cGood) на "корабль"(cShip), а ячейки вокруг нее на "занятые"(cBad).

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  //тип ячейки
  TKind = (cBad,cShip,cGood);
  TCellGrid = class;
  //ячейка поля
  TCell = class
    fKind:TKind;
    fVert:integer;
    fHorz:integer;
  public
    constructor Create(vert:integer;horz:integer);
  end;
  //поле
  TCellGrid = class
    fACells:array[0..9,0..9]of TCell;
  public
    function isGood(cell:TCell;ind:integer):boolean;
    function NewShip(ind:integer):boolean;
    function SetShip(cell:TCell;ind:integer):boolean;
    procedure toFile(fileName:string);
    constructor Create;
  end;
{ TCell }

constructor TCell.Create;
begin
  fKind:=cGood;
  fVert:=vert;
  fHorz:=horz;
end;

{ TCellGrid }

constructor TCellGrid.Create;
var i,j:integer;
begin
  for i:=0to 9do
    for j:=0to 9do begin
      fACells[i,j]:= TCell.Create(i,j);
    end;
end;

function TCellGrid.isGood(cell:TCell;ind:integer): boolean;
var
  i,j:integer;
  bln:boolean;
begin
  Result:=true;
  case ind of
  1:for i:=cell.fVert-1 to cell.fVert+1 do
      for j:= cell.fHorz-1 to cell.fHorz+1 do
        if(i>-1)and(j>-1)and(i<10)and(j<10)then
          if(TKind(fACells[i,j].fKind)=cShip)then
            Result:=false;
  2:if isGood(cell,1) then begin
      for i:=cell.fVert-1 to cell.fVert+1 do
        for j:= cell.fHorz-1 to cell.fHorz+1 do
          if(i>-1)and(j>-1)and(i<10)and(j<10)then
            if(i<>cell.fVert) or (j<>cell.fHorz)then
              if isGood(fACells[i,j],1)then begin
                Result:=true;
                if(bln)then begin
                  bln:= not bln;
                  isGood(fACells[i,j],2);
                end;
              end;
    end
    else Result:=false;
  3:begin
      bln:=true;
      Result:= isGood(cell,2);
    end;
  end;
end;

function TCellGrid.NewShip(ind:integer): boolean;
var
  i,j:integer;
begin
  Result:=false;
  case ind of
  1:for i:=0 to 9 do
      for j:=0 to 9 do
        if isGood(fACells[i,j],1) then begin
          SetShip(fACells[i,j],1);
          Result:=true;
          Exit;
        end;
  2:for i:=0 to 9 do if not Result then
      for j:=0 to 9 do if not Result then
        if isGood(fACells[i,j],2) then begin
          SetShip(fACells[i,j],2);
          Result:=true;
        end;
  3:for i:=0 to 9 do if not Result then
      for j:=0 to 9 do if not Result then
        if isGood(fACells[i,j],3) then begin
          SetShip(fACells[i,j],3);
          Result:=true;
        end;
  end;
end;

var
  grid: TCellGrid;
  i:integer;

function TCellGrid.SetShip(cell:TCell;ind: integer): boolean;
var
  i,j:integer;
  a:array of TCell;
  k:boolean;
  n:integer;
  procedure changeCells(i:integer;j:integer);
  begin
    if(i>-1)and(j>-1)and(i<10)and(j<10)then
      if(i<>cell.fVert) or (j<>cell.fHorz)then
        if isGood(fACells[i,j],1)then
          a[n]:=fACells[i,j];
  end;
  function change(cell:TCell):boolean;
  var i,j:integer;  i1:integer;
    bln:boolean;
  begin
    k:=boolean(random(2));
    if k then begin
      for i:=cell.fVert to cell.fVert do
        for j:= cell.fHorz-1 to cell.fHorz+1 do
          if(i>-1)and(j>-1)and(i<10)and(j<10)then
            if(i<>cell.fVert) or (j<>cell.fHorz)then begin
              bln:=true;
              for i1:=0to n-1do
                if (fACells[i,j]=a[i1])then
                  bln:=false;
              if bln then
                if isGood(fACells[i,j],1)then begin
                  a[n]:=fACells[i,j];
                  inc(n);
                  if (ind=3)and(n=3) then
                    Result:=true;
                  if (ind=3)and(n=2) then
                    change(fACells[i,j]);
                end;
            end;
    end
    else begin
      for i:=cell.fVert-1 to cell.fVert+1 do
        for j:= cell.fHorz to cell.fHorz do
          if(i>-1)and(j>-1)and(i<10)and(j<10)then
            if(i<>cell.fVert) or (j<>cell.fHorz)then begin
              bln:=true;
              for i1:=0to n-1do
                if (fACells[i,j]=a[i1])then
                  bln:=false;
              if bln then
                if isGood(fACells[i,j],1)then begin
                  a[n]:=fACells[i,j];
                  inc(n);
                  if (ind=3)and(n=3)then
                    Result:=true;
                  if (ind=3)and(n=2) then
                    change(fACells[i,j]);
                end;
            end;
    end;
  end;
begin
  Result:=true;
  n:=0;
  case ind of
    1:begin
        for i:=cell.fVert-1 to cell.fVert+1 do
          for j:= cell.fHorz-1 to cell.fHorz+1 do
            if(i>-1)and(j>-1)and(i<10)and(j<10)then
              if(cell.fVert=i)and(cell.fHorz=j)then
                TKind(grid.fACells[i,j].fKind):=cShip
              else
                if TKind(grid.fACells[i,j].fKind)<> cShip then
                  TKind(grid.fACells[i,j].fKind):=cBad;
      end;
    2:begin
        SetLength(a,sizeOf(cell)*2);
        k:=boolean(random(2));
        if isGood(cell,1) then begin
          a[n]:=cell;
          inc(n);
          if k then
            for i:=cell.fVert to cell.fVert do
              for j:= cell.fHorz-1 to cell.fHorz+1 do
                changeCells(i,j)
          else
            for i:=cell.fVert-1 to cell.fVert+1 do
              for j:= cell.fHorz to cell.fHorz do
                changeCells(i,j)
        end;
        for i:=0to 1 do
          SetShip(a[i],1);
      end;
    3:begin
        SetLength(a,sizeOf(cell)*3);

        if isGood(cell,1) then begin
          a[n]:=cell;
          inc(n);
          change(cell);
        end;
        for i:=0to 2 do
          SetShip(a[i],1);
      end;
  end;
end;

procedure TCellGrid.toFile(fileName: string);
var
  f:TextFile;i,j:integer;
begin
  AssignFile(f,fileName);
  Rewrite(f);
  for i:=0to 9do
    for j:=0to 9do
      case integer(grid.fACells[i,j].fKind) of
      0: Writeln(inttostr(i):3, inttostr(j):3, 'bad':6);
      1: Writeln(inttostr(i):3, inttostr(j):3, 'ship':6);
      2: Writeln(inttostr(i):3, inttostr(j):3, 'good':6);
      end;
  CloseFile(f);
end;

begin
  grid:= TCellGrid.Create;
  for i:=0to 3 do
    grid.NewShip(1);
  for i:=0to 2do
    grid.NewShip(2);
  for i:=0to 1do
    grid.NewShip(3);
  grid.toFile('t.txt');
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: Всё же ship, а не sheep.

Comment: абсолютно с вами согласен)

Comment: ужасная простыня. не стоит так писать. вложенные циклы в кейсах - за гранью добра и зла.  
при этом весь алгоритм заключается в сложении двух матриц и проверки результата.