# Генерация кораблей в Delphi. Морской бой.

Tags: delphi

Я сделал генерацию кораблей по правилам морского боя, чего я пытался добиться в своем предыдущем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/193815/delphi-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F). Теперь я не могу понять почему у меня корабли  генерируются иногда правильно а иногда нет! Вот весь код генерации кораблей:

```
    procedure TForm1.generate_ships(mine:boolean);
var i, x, y, t:Byte;  // i - счетчик,  x,y - координаты,
//t - тип(вертикальный/горизонтальный)
f: Boolean;
field:Area;
begin
  if mine then field:=My_field else field:=Com_field;
  // 4-палубный
  f:=False;

  x:=Random(7)+1;
  y:=Random(7)+1;
  t:=random(2);
  if t = 0 then begin
  field.Field[x,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[1].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[1].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[1].Y:=y;

  field.Field[x-1,y]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y+1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y+1]:=cc_miss;

  field.Field[x+1,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x+1,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[2].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[2].X:=x+1;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[2].Y:=y;

  field.Field[x+2,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x+2,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+2,y+1]:= cc_miss; 
  field.Ships.Four_ship[3].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[3].X:=x+2;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[3].Y:=y;

  field.Field[x+3,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x+3,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+3,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+4,y]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+4,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+4,y-1]:= cc_miss; 
  field.Ships.Four_ship[4].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[4].X:=x+3;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[4].Y:=y;

                end else begin
  field.Field[x,y]:= cc_fill; 
  field.Ships.Four_ship[1].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[1].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[1].Y:=y;

  field.Field[x,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y]:=cc_miss;


  field.Field[x,y+1]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x-1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[2].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[2].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[2].Y:=y+1;

  field.Field[x,y+2]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x-1,y+2]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+2]:= cc_miss;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[3].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[3].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[3].Y:=y+2;

  field.Field[x,y+3]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x-1,y+3]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+3]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y+4]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+4]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y+4]:= cc_miss; 
  field.Ships.Four_ship[4].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[4].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Four_ship[4].Y:=y+3;

                         end;
  //
    // 3-палубный
  f:=False;
  t:=random(2);
  if t = 1 then begin
  while not f do   begin
  x:=Random(8)+1;
  y:=Random(8)+1;
  if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)or
  (field.Field[x,y+1]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y+1]= cc_miss)or
  (field.Field[x,y+2]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y+2]= cc_miss)) then f:=true;
  end;  end else begin
                       while not f do   begin
  x:=Random(8)+1;
  y:=Random(8)+1;
  if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)or
  (field.Field[x+1,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x+1,y]= cc_miss)or
  (field.Field[x+2,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x+2,y]= cc_miss)) then f:=true;
  end;
                 end;

  if t = 0 then begin
  field.Field[x,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[1].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[1].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[1].Y:=y;

  field.Field[x-1,y]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y+1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y+1]:=cc_miss;

  field.Field[x+1,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x+1,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[2].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[2].X:=x+1;
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[2].Y:=y;

  field.Field[x+2,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x+2,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+2,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+3,y]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+3,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+3,y-1]:= cc_miss; 
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[3].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[3].X:=x+2;
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[3].Y:=y;

                end else begin
  field.Field[x,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[1].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[1].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[1].Y:=y;

  field.Field[x,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y]:=cc_miss;


  field.Field[x,y+1]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x-1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+1]:= cc_miss; 
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[2].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[2].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[2].Y:=y+1;

  field.Field[x,y+2]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x-1,y+2]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+2]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y+3]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+3]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y+3]:= cc_miss; 
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[3].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[3].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Three_ship1[3].Y:=y+2;

                         end;  
  //...

  f:=False;
  t:=random(2);
  if t = 1 then begin
  while not f do   begin
  x:=Random(8)+1;
  y:=Random(8)+1;
  if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)or
  (field.Field[x,y+1]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y+1]= cc_miss)or
  (field.Field[x,y+2]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y+2]= cc_miss)) then f:=true;
  end;  end else begin
                       while not f do   begin
  x:=Random(8)+1;
  y:=Random(8)+1;
  if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)or
  (field.Field[x+1,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x+1,y]= cc_miss)or
  (field.Field[x+2,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x+2,y]= cc_miss)) then f:=true;
  end;
                 end;

  if t = 0 then begin
  field.Field[x,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[1].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[1].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[1].Y:=y;

  field.Field[x-1,y]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y+1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y+1]:=cc_miss;

  field.Field[x+1,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x+1,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[2].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[2].X:=x+1;
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[2].Y:=y;

  field.Field[x+2,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x+2,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+2,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+3,y]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+3,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+3,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[3].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[3].X:=x+2;
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[3].Y:=y;

                end else begin
  field.Field[x,y]:= cc_fill; 
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[1].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[1].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[1].Y:=y;

  field.Field[x,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y]:=cc_miss;


  field.Field[x,y+1]:= cc_fill;  
  field.Field[x-1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+1]:= cc_miss; 
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[2].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[2].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[2].Y:=y+1;

  field.Field[x,y+2]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x-1,y+2]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+2]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y+3]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+3]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y+3]:= cc_miss; 
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[3].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[3].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Three_ship2[3].Y:=y+2;

                         end;  


      // 2-палубный
  f:=False;
  t:=random(2);
  if t = 1 then begin
  while not f do   begin
  x:=Random(9)+1;
  y:=Random(9)+1;
  if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)or
  (field.Field[x,y+1]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y+1]= cc_miss)) then f:=true;
  end;  end else begin
                       while not f do   begin
  x:=Random(9)+1;
  y:=Random(9)+1;
  if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)or
  (field.Field[x+1,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x+1,y]= cc_miss)) then f:=true;
  end;
                 end;

  if t = 0 then begin
  field.Field[x,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Two_ship1[1].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Two_ship1[1].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Two_ship1[1].Y:=y;

  field.Field[x-1,y]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y+1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y+1]:=cc_miss;

  field.Field[x+1,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x+1,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+2,y]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+2,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+2,y-1]:= cc_miss; 
  field.Ships.Two_ship1[2].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Two_ship1[2].X:=x+1;
  field.Ships.Two_ship1[2].Y:=y;

                end else begin
  field.Field[x,y]:= cc_fill; 
  field.Ships.Two_ship1[1].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Two_ship1[1].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Two_ship1[1].Y:=y;

  field.Field[x,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y]:=cc_miss;


  field.Field[x,y+1]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x-1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y+2]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+2]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y+2]:= cc_miss;
  field.Ships.Two_ship1[2].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Two_ship1[2].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Two_ship1[2].Y:=y+1;

                         end;   

  // ...2
  f:=False;
  t:=random(2);
  if t = 1 then begin
  while not f do   begin
  x:=Random(9)+1;
  y:=Random(9)+1;
  if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)or
  (field.Field[x,y+1]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y+1]= cc_miss)) then f:=true;
  end;  end else begin
                       while not f do   begin
  x:=Random(9)+1;
  y:=Random(9)+1;
  if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)or
  (field.Field[x+1,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x+1,y]= cc_miss)) then f:=true;
  end;
                 end;

  if t = 0 then begin
  field.Field[x,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Two_ship2[1].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Two_ship2[1].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Two_ship2[1].Y:=y;

  field.Field[x-1,y]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y+1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y+1]:=cc_miss;

  field.Field[x+1,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x+1,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+2,y]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+2,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+2,y-1]:= cc_miss; 
  field.Ships.Two_ship2[1].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Two_ship2[1].X:=x+1;
  field.Ships.Two_ship2[1].Y:=y;

                end else begin
  field.Field[x,y]:= cc_fill; 
  field.Ships.Two_ship2[1].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Two_ship2[1].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Two_ship2[1].Y:=y;

  field.Field[x,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y]:=cc_miss;


  field.Field[x,y+1]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x-1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y+2]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+2]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y+2]:= cc_miss; 
  field.Ships.Two_ship2[2].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Two_ship2[2].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Two_ship2[2].Y:=y+1;

                         end;

  // ...3
  f:=False;
  t:=random(2);
  if t = 1 then begin
  while not f do   begin
  x:=Random(9)+1;
  y:=Random(9)+1;
  if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)or
  (field.Field[x,y+1]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y+1]= cc_miss)) then f:=true;
  end;  end else begin
                       while not f do   begin
  x:=Random(9)+1;
  y:=Random(9)+1;
  if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)or
  (field.Field[x+1,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x+1,y]= cc_miss)) then f:=true;
  end;
                 end;

  if t = 0 then begin
  field.Field[x,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Two_ship3[1].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Two_ship3[1].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Two_ship3[1].Y:=y;

  field.Field[x-1,y]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y+1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y+1]:=cc_miss;

  field.Field[x+1,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x+1,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+2,y]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+2,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+2,y-1]:= cc_miss;  
  field.Ships.Two_ship3[2].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Two_ship3[2].X:=x+1;
  field.Ships.Two_ship3[2].Y:=y;

                end else begin
  field.Field[x,y]:= cc_fill;   
  field.Ships.Two_ship3[1].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Two_ship3[1].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Two_ship3[1].Y:=y;

  field.Field[x,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y-1]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y]:=cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y]:=cc_miss;


  field.Field[x,y+1]:= cc_fill;
  field.Field[x-1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y+2]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+2]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y+2]:= cc_miss;   
  field.Ships.Two_ship3[2].state:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.Two_ship3[2].X:=x;
  field.Ships.Two_ship3[2].Y:=y+1;

                         end;

  // 1-палубные
  f:= False;
      while not f do   begin
  x:=Random(10)+1;
  y:=Random(10)+1;
  if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)) then f:=true;
  end;
  field.Field[x-1,y]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.One_ship1[1].state:=cc_fill;
  field.Ships.One_ship1[1].X:=x;
  field.Ships.One_ship1[1].Y:=y;

   f:=False;
    while not f do   begin
  x:=Random(10)+1;
  y:=Random(10)+1;
  if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)) then f:=true;
  end;
  field.Field[x-1,y]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.One_ship2[1].state:=cc_fill;
  field.Ships.One_ship2[1].X:=x;
  field.Ships.One_ship2[1].Y:=y;

  f:= False;
      while not f do   begin
  x:=Random(10)+1;
  y:=Random(10)+1;
  if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)) then f:=true;
  end;
  field.Field[x-1,y]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.One_ship3[1].state:=cc_fill;
  field.Ships.One_ship3[1].X:=x;
  field.Ships.One_ship3[1].Y:=y;

    f:= False;
      while not f do   begin
  x:=Random(10)+1;
  y:=Random(10)+1;
  if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)) then f:=true;
  end;
  field.Field[x-1,y]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x-1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x+1,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y-1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y+1]:= cc_miss;
  field.Field[x,y]:= cc_fill;
  field.Ships.One_ship4[1].state:=cc_fill;
  field.Ships.One_ship4[1].X:=x;
  field.Ships.One_ship4[1].Y:=y;

  // Очистка от точек
  for x:=1 to 10 do begin
                      for y:=1 to 10 do begin
                                          if field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss then field.Field[x,y]:= cc_none;
                                        end;
                    end;
  if mine then my_field:=field else Com_field:=field;

end;
```

Если хотите, могу скинуть exe-шник готовой программы...

Comment: советую пересмотреть свой алгоритм генерации... и сделать менее линейным.

Comment: Менее линейным? Вы предлагаете использовать циклы?

Comment: очень много копипаста. я увидел как минимум 16 кусков, которые можно вынести в 2-3 отдельные процедуры. Будет заметно короче и красивее. А там и другие оптимизации можно будет увидеть.

Comment: Отформатируйте код. И, если ошибка не уйдет сама по себе, задайте вопрос и приведите исправленный код.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

сделать:
 1. класс корабля (в свойствах будут: количество палуб, состояние палуб, местоположение палуб и тд. В методах: конструктор, деструктор, размещение корабля на поле, получение повреждений и тд.)
 2. цикл размещения кораблей
 3. серьезный рефакторинг, ибо подобная портянка кода в одной процедуре не есть хорошо. Это как минимум нечитаемо. Хотя бы потому, что мне (и не только мне) лень это читать. Это тяжело писать с нуля и сопровождать - вы в одном месте поставите неправильную переменную, и у вас умрет **ВЕСЬ** алгоритм. И **естественно**, что вы не можете найти ошибку.

---

По поводу рефакторинга:
 1. Вынесите одинаковый функционал в отдельные функции и процедуры, и по необходимости вызывайте их. У вас **ОЧЕНЬ** много повторного кода.
 2. Каждая функция и процедура, в идеале, должна выполнять **одно** действие. 
 4. Пожалуйста, пишите комментарии к коду. Пожалейте других программистов.
 3. Почитайте статьи про форматирование текста. Ваше сочинение крайне неудобно читать из-за отсутствия нормальных отступов. Эта конструкция вообще убила:

```
      if t = 1 then begin
      while not f do   begin
      x:=Random(8)+1;
      y:=Random(8)+1;
      if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)or
      (field.Field[x,y+1]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y+1]= cc_miss)or
      (field.Field[x,y+2]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y+2]= cc_miss)) then f:=true;
      end;  end else begin
                           while not f do   begin
      x:=Random(8)+1;
      y:=Random(8)+1;
      if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)or
      (field.Field[x+1,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x+1,y]= cc_miss)or
      (field.Field[x+2,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x+2,y]= cc_miss)) then f:=true;
      end;
                     end;
```

Согласитесь, что в таком виде она выглядит аппетитнее:

```
  if t = 1 then  
    begin  
      while not f do  
        begin  
          x:=Random(8)+1;  
          y:=Random(8)+1;  
          if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)or  
          (field.Field[x,y+1]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y+1]= cc_miss)or  
          (field.Field[x,y+2]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y+2]= cc_miss)) then   
            f:=true;  
        end;  
    end  
  else   
    begin  
      while not f do  
        begin  
          x:=Random(8)+1;  
          y:=Random(8)+1;  
          if not((field.Field[x,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x,y]= cc_miss)or  
          (field.Field[x+1,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x+1,y]= cc_miss)or  
          (field.Field[x+2,y]= cc_fill)or(field.Field[x+2,y]= cc_miss)) then  
            f:=true;  
        end;  
    end;
```

*Да, у меня есть привычка переносить begin на новую строку с отступом. Но о вкусах, как говорится, не спорят.*

---

В целом приведенный вами код является ярким примером того, как делать **не надо**. Когда вы приведете архитектуру и формат кода к нормальному виду тогда и ошибку найдете.

Comment: Полностью согласен с Вашим мнением! Тот код, который я Вам представил, я всего лишь скопировал из своей программы, и я не посмотрев как он скопировался, отправил его сюда.

Comment: @Андрющенко Андрей еще не поздно поправить отступы :) Разбираться в коде крайне тяжело.

Comment: @Андрющенко Андрей ты сейчас остановился на генерации?, всё остальное работает?

Comment: @Андрющенко Андрей: то, что ваш проект горит, не значит, что мы должны разбираться в неудобочитаемом коде, проблема всё же у вас, а не у нас.

Comment: @IVsevolod согласен! Вот если хотите, ознакомьтесь с проектом --> https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1NgZiHP3pv9bzlhblA3cEpnb1U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Андрющенко Андрей, попробуйте опубликовать [вот здесь][1]


  [1]: http://govnokod.ru/

Answer (score 1):

Вот, посидел немного, подумал, написал генерацию. Заранее **извиняюсь что на C#**, просто под рукой не было компилятора Delphi и Pascal. Думаю алгоритм можешь посмотреть, или преобразовать в Delphi.

Для начала массив поля (0 - пустое поле, 1 - корабль, 2 - рядом корабль). 2-ка нужна для генерации, от нее потом можно избавиться.

```
    public int[,] arr = new int[10, 10];
```

Функция определения Можно ли поставить корабль на заданные координаты, с заданным поворотом, с заданным размером:

```
    bool canSetShip(int x, int y, int t, int size)
    {
        bool _ret = true;
        for (int i = 0; _ret && i < size; i++)
        {
            if (t == 0 && arr[x + i, y] > 0)
                _ret = false;
            else if (t == 1 && arr[x, y + 1] > 0)
                _ret = false;
        }
        return _ret;
    }
```

Дальше функция Установки корабля на место, с точно такими же параметрами:

```
    void setShip(int x, int y, int t, int size)
    {
        int _minX = 10, _maxX = -1, _minY = 10, _maxY = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            int _x = x;
            int _y = y;
            if (t == 0)
                _x = x + i;
            else
                _y = y + i;
            // ставим корабль на поле
            arr[_x, _y] = 1;
            if (_x < _minX) _minX = _x;
            if (_x > _maxX) _maxX = _x;
            if (_y < _minY) _minY = _y;
            if (_y > _maxY) _maxY = _y;
        }

        // заполняем соседние ячейки
        for (int i = _minX - 1; i <= _maxX + 1; i++)
        {
            if (i >= 0 && i < 10 && _minY > 0 && _minY <= 9)
                arr[i, _minY - 1] = 2;
            if (i >= 0 && i < 10 && _minY >= 0 && _maxY < 9)
                arr[i, _maxY + 1] = 2;
        }

        for (int j = _minY - 1; j <= _maxY + 1; j++)
        {
            if (_minX > 0 && _minX <= 9 && j >= 0 && j < 10)
                arr[_minX - 1, j] = 2;
            if (_maxX >= 0 && _maxX < 9 && j >= 0 && j < 10)
                arr[_maxX + 1, j] = 2;
        }
    }
```

Ну и сама генерация.

```
        Random r = new Random();
        // очищаем массив
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                arr[i, j] = 0;
        // массив кол-ва кораблей соответствующего размера (т.е. cShip[0] - кол-во однопалубников, cShip[1] - кол-во двухпалубников и т.д.)
        int[] cShip = new int[4] { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
        for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int maxW = 10 - i;
            for (int z = 0; z < cShip[i-1]; z++)
            {
                int zx = r.Next(maxW - 1);
                int zy = r.Next(maxW - 1);
                int zt = r.Next(1);
                // ищем ближайшую клетку, свободную от случайной позиции
                while (!canSetShip(zx, zy, zt, i))
                {
                    if (zx < maxW)
                        zx++;
                    else if (zy < maxW)
                    {
                        zy++;
                        zx = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        zy = 0;
                        zx = 0;
                    }
                }
                setShip(zx, zy, zt, i);
            }
        }
```

**p.s.** если дома будет время, могу переписать на Delphi.

Comment: Известно, что лучшая стратегия расстановки кораблей - линкор, крейсеры и эсминцы сгрудить в одном углу, а подлодки равномерно разбросать по свободному  месту

Comment: @renegator задача в не наилучшем варианте, а просто чтобы правильно расставлял.  Вы можете предложить свой алгоритм расстановки :)

Comment: Я у курсе так то. Комментарий он на то и комментарий чтобы отличаться от ответа не правда ли. Предложить могу, программка на дельфи, которую недавно набросал занимает чуть более 900 строк